# Unable to access table tag within BeautifulSoup--shows as declaration instead of tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, tags

I am running Python3 using Jupyter Notebook. I am trying to select the table row tags with class attribute 'Company' on [this page](http://theacsi.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=149&catid=&Itemid=214&i=Airlines), however no tags are able to be selected past a certain point in the soup. When I run the findAll, it results in an empty list. The soup index containing the table is 21, however that shows as a bs4.element.Declaration instead of a tag, which is probably why the findAll is returning nothing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs  
import requests
url = 'http://theacsi.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=149&catid=&Itemid=214&i=Airlines'
r = requests.get(url, headers={
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'
        })
airlinesSatPage = r.content       
soup = bs(airlinesSatPage, "html.parser")
allRows = soup.findAll('tr',{'class':'Company'})
print(allRows)
```

Any ideas what is going on or what I can do to access those tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the `html.parser` cannot handle the HTML markup being returned from that URL. Switching to the `lxml` parser resolves the issue, but this does require a separate `pip install lxml`.

So in summary, first:

```
pip install lxml
```

And then change the parser in your code:

```
soup = bs(airlinesSatPage, "lxml")
```

When run, prints:

```
[<tr class="Company"><td class="Company"> <a href="https://www.theacsi.org..., ]
```